# Editing Pixel Values in java

Tags: java, pixel

I have a class Pixel that has methods getRed, getBlue, getGreen, setRed, setBlue, setGreen (r,g,b)
and so far everything works individually but when i put it TOGETHER setGreen and setBlue don't work. Am I doing something wrong with the masking?

```
public class Pixel {
    int pixel;
    public Pixel (int pixel) {
        this.pixel = pixel;
    }
    public int getRed() {
        int red = pixel >> 16;
        red = red & (0xFF);
        return red;   
    }
    public int getGreen() {
        int green = pixel >> 8;
        green = green & (0xFF);
        return green;
    }
    public int getBlue() {
        int blue = pixel;
        blue = blue & (0xFF);
        return blue;
    }
    public void setRed(int red) {
        pixel = (pixel & ~(0xFFFF0000)) << 16;
        pixel= ((red << 16))|pixel ;   
    }
    public void setGreen(int value) {
        pixel = (pixel & ~(0xFF00FF00)) << 8;
        pixel= (value << 8) |pixel; 
    }
    public void setBlue(int value) {
        pixel = (pixel & ~(0xFFFFFF00));
        pixel= (value) |pixel; 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pixel p3 = new Pixel(0xFF000000);
        System.out.printf("rgb = (%d, %d, %d)\n", p3.getRed(), p3.getGreen(), p3.getBlue());

        p3.setRed(42);
        p3.setGreen(18);
        p3.setBlue(225);
        System.out.printf("rgb = (%d, %d, %d)\n", p3.getRed(), p3.getGreen(), p3.getBlue());

        p3.setRed(-1);
        p3.setGreen(500);
        p3.setBlue(1000);
        System.out.printf("rgb = (%d, %d, %d)\n", p3.getRed(), p3.getGreen(), p3.getBlue());
    }   
}
```

I should be getting this as my result:

```
rgb = (0, 0, 0)
rgb = (42, 18, 225)
rgb = (255, 244, 232)
```

but this is what im getting

```
rgb = (0, 0, 0)
rgb = (0, 0, 225)
rgb = (0, 3, 232)
```

Comment: How do you want the bit layout in your `int`?  Should it be the standard `RRGGBB` (where one letter denotes four bits)?

Comment: A pixel is a 32-bit int value that can be interpreted as a sequence of four 8-bit values. The first 8-bit value is the alpha channel. We will ignore that. The next three 8-bit values are the red, green, and blue components of the pixel, respectively.

Comment: they are 8 bits not four i believe

Comment: Four bits per letter (in accordance with hex), so `RR` is one byte.

Comment: yeah... but still dont know why this isnt working together but works individually T.T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for example your `setGreen` method:

```
public void setGreen(int value) {
    pixel = (pixel & ~(0xFF00FF00)) << 8;
    pixel = (value << 8) | pixel; 
}
```

Initially, your `pixel` is `AARRGGBB`. First, you are setting the `GG` part in the current value of `pixel` to 0 correctly (ignoring alpha for now).  `(pixel & ~(0xFF00FF00)) == (AARRGGBB & 0x00FF00FF) == 00RR00BB`.  However, next you shift that value 8 bits to the left, so you get `RR00BB00`.  Next, you are (correctly) left-shifting the green value you got as a parameter.  You'll get `(000000GG << 8) == 0000GG00`.  And finally, you are or'ing that with the value from before: `(RR00BB00 | 0000GG00) == RR00XX00` where the `X`es are some garbage that originate from or'ing together the old blue with the new green bits.  Can you see what to fix?

There is another issue in the `setBlue` method.  `(pixel & ~(0xFFFFFF00)) == (AARRGGBB & 000000FF) == 000000BB`.  Compare that with the (correct) mask for `setGreen` above.

Finally, your methods seem to be supposed to handle invalid values (–1, 500, 1000) gracefully.  So you should set all but the last 8 bits of your arguments to 0.  I'm only suggesting that because your required output seems to ask for that.  In a well-written Java program, it would b better to throw an exception if out-of-range values are passed, rather than silently ignoring the invalid bits.  Alternatively, you could change your methods to accept a `byte` instead of an `int`.  This would be the best solution since now it would be outright impossible to pass an invalid argument.

Putting this together, here is how it could work.  I have also polished the code a little so we can hopefully see more easily what is going on.  The shifts by 0 bits are of course useless but I include them for optical reasons.

```
public final class Pixel {

    private int value;

    public Pixel (int rgb) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getRed() {
        return (this.value >> 16) & 0xFF;
    }

    public int getGreen() {
        return (this.value >>  8) & 0xFF;
    }

    public int getBlue() {
        return (this.value >>  0) & 0xFF;
    }

    public void setRed(final int r) {
        this.value = (this.value & 0xFF00FFFF) | ((r & 0xFF) << 16);
    }

    public void setGreen(final int g) {
        this.value = (this.value & 0xFFFF00FF) | ((g & 0xFF) <<  8);
    }

    public void setBlue(final int b) {
        this.value = (this.value & 0xFFFFFF00) | ((b & 0xFF) <<  0);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("rgb = (%3d, %3d, %3d)",
                             this.getRed(),
                             this.getGreen(),
                             this.getBlue());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Pixel pixel = new Pixel(0);
        System.out.println(pixel);
        pixel.setRed(42);
        pixel.setGreen(18);
        pixel.setBlue(225);
        System.out.println(pixel);
        pixel.setRed(-1);
        pixel.setGreen(500);
        pixel.setBlue(1000);
        System.out.println(pixel);
    }
}
```

Output of running the above program:

```
rgb = (  0,   0,   0)
rgb = ( 42,  18, 225)
rgb = (255, 244, 232)
```

Comment: is the problem that i am shifting value ?

Comment: Yes, the left-shift of `pixel` (or what remains from it after and'ing out some parts) is wrong.

Comment: I tried doing that before just taking out the first left shift and it still doesn't work

Comment: sorry if I may seem stupid but this is my first time working with or's and &'s so what im doing im not really sure

Comment: i mean what im doing is right in a way since they are working individually but there must be something wrong with the masks because when i use them all together it doesn't work on red and green

Comment: @Panthy You're welcome.  Now you've had the chance to discover the solution yourself, I will update my answer with the code so we can make this a reference for people seeking to solve the same problem in the future.